# How do I stop Socket.io spaming connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making a socket.io chat app. When I either start the server or make the first connection it spams the callback. The callback does not stop until the server is stopped. I think the error is coming from the html file, but I'm not exactly sure. Thank you for your time. 
IO callback:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) =>{
  connections.push('socket')
  console.log('Connection made \n ' + connections.length + ' made')

  socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
  connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1)
  console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets left', connections.length)
  })
})
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
          margin: 30px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="well">
            <h3>Online Users</h3>
            <ul class="list-group" id="users"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>
          <form id="messageForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Enter Message</label>
              <textarea id="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
              <br>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <script>
        var socket = io()
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see the second line you are adding `string` to the array `connections`. On line 2 of server. `connections.push('socket')`

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: You should use `connections.push(socket)`

Comment: It worked but I don't understand why.

Comment: ok bro see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on **line 2**. You are pushing `string` i.e `'socket'` to `connections`. `'socket'` doesnot refer to the `socket` variable in the argument. You need to push `socket` not `'socket'` because its just combinations of letters not variable

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) =>{
  connections.push(socket) // this line is changed
  console.log('Connection made \n ' + connections.length + ' made')

  socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
  connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1)
  console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets left', connections.length)
  })
})
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I was using `connections.push('socket')` pushing the word socket and not the parameter.